# associative array which name is a variable

Tags: zsh

I have this setup :

```
typeset -A network
network[interface]=eth0,eth1

typeset -A eth0
eth0[dhcp]=yes
...
typeset -A eth1
eth1[dhcp]=yes
...
```

I want to get the dhcp value for each value of network[interface], I have this setup :

```
for InterfaceToCreate in $(echo ${network[interface]/,/ }) ; do
(some stuff)
case ${InterfaceToCreate[dhcp]} in
(some stuff)
```

It doesn't work as normal if I try with

```
${!InterfaceToCreate[dhcp]}
\${${InterfaceToCreate}[dhcp]}
```

I even tried with eval for the same result.

Comment: Are they any other keys in the `network` array? Why not use a regular indexed array `interfaces=(eth0 eth1)` instead?

Comment: There is other key in network (`dns1`, `dns2`, `proxy`, ...) , so I need to use an associative array, 'cause indices's order could change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default values of parameters are not interpreted as further parameter names. So `${${foo}}` behaves just like `${foo}` (See [*Nested Substitutions*](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Rules)). This behavior can be changed with the [parameter expansion flag](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) `P`. For example `${(P)${foo}}` would evaluate `${foo}` and use its value as name for a parameter substitution.

So you can achieve the desired effect like this:

```sh
typeset -A network eth0 eth1
network[interface]=eth0,eth1
eth0[dhcp]=yes
eth1[dhcp]=no

for InterfaceToCreate in ${(s:,:)network[interface]} ; do
    case ${${(P)InterfaceToCreate}[dhcp]} in
        yes)
            print $InterfaceToCreate DHCP 
            ;;
        *)  
            print $InterfaceToCreate no DHCP
            ;;
    esac
done
```

This should show

```
eth0 DHCP
eth1 no DHCP
```

I also would suggest using the [parameter expansion flag](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) `s:string:` to split the comma separated list instead of going the roundabout way with `echo` and command substitutions.

Comment: Thanks for the « s:string: » !

However the ${(P)${foo}} won't work ...
Here is a test case :

`typeset -A eth0`
`eth0[dhcp]=yes`
`typeset -A eth1`
`eth1[dhcp]=yes`
``
`InterfaceToCreate=eth0`
``
`echo ${${(P)InterfaceToCreate}[dhcp]}`
`# blank output`


This work as expected :
${(Pkv)InterfaceToCreate} , returns key/value, only the [key] don't work if secified

Comment: I just tested it again - I even copy-pasted the lines from your comment - and it works just fine for me, even with default settings (`zsh -f`). I also could not find anything in the manpage that would indicate that this behavior is in any way configurable.

Comment: with `zsh -f`, it's ok ... I'll try to find which option is causing this strange behavior ... Anyway Thank you.

Comment: Just calling `setopt` should show all options that differ from the default settings.

Comment: in the 5.0 version of zsh, can't work ... Use 5.3 instead and it's good